# Toggle div and set cookie to save jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I use the following code to toggle a specific div and save the setting with a cookie, so that it wil keep the change.

But for some reason the save cookie section is not working well. It seems that the cookie is not saved when using the previous browser buttons for example.

What am I missing in my current code the perfectly add a cookie and check it.

```js
function getCookieValue(a) {
  var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
  return b ? b.pop() : '';
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var redEl = $('input#togglebtw');

  if (document.cookie.indexOf('togglebtw=') != -1) {
    redEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("togglebtw")));
  }

  if (redEl.prop("checked")) {
    $(".price-container .price-including-tax").hide();
    $(".price-container .price-excluding-tax").show();
  } else {
    $(".price-container .price-excluding-tax").hide();
    $(".price-container .price-including-tax").show();
  }

  $('input#togglebtw').click(function() {

    var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 31);
    expiryDate = expiryDate.toUTCString();

    if ($(this).attr("class") == "btwToggler") {
      if (redEl.prop("checked")) {
        $(".price-container .price-including-tax").hide();
        $(".price-container .price-excluding-tax").show();
      } else {
        $(".price-container .price-excluding-tax").hide();
        $(".price-container .price-including-tax").show();
      }
      document.cookie = "togglebtw=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="togglebtw" class="btwToggler" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: If you do not need the cookie on the server, then the logical choice is localStorage (cross sessions) or sessionStorage (within the same session)

Comment: if you DO need the cookie on the server, then use an [EXISTING cookie script instead of using your own](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), Always rely on thousands of testers to have done the job for you.

Comment: To find out what's wrong with code, the first order of debugging is to `console.log` everything to make sure variables and returns values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: @mplungjan The cookies does not need to be stored on the server, so it also can be a local cookie. Can you help me out, what code changes I should make to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local or sessionStorage, then you do not need to worry about the cookie is correct or not

Try this simplified version

```js
const checkBTW = function() {
  const checked = $('#togglebtw').is(":checked");
  $(".price-container .price-including-tax").toggle(!checked);
  $(".price-container .price-excluding-tax").toggle(checked);
  localStorage.setItem("togglebtw",checked?"true":"false");
};
$(function() {
  $('#togglebtw')
    .on("click",checkBTW)
    .prop("checked",localStorage.getItem("togglebtw")==="true"); 
  checkBTW();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect :)